# Выводится черный прямоугольник

Tags: linux, c, opengl, opengles

Задаю в функции инициализации кнопку и цвет.

```
#include "menu.h"

struct button *btn_new_game;

void init_menu ( )
{
        btn_new_game = calloc ( 1, sizeof ( struct button ) );
        button_init ( btn_new_game );
        button_set_percent ( btn_new_game, 10, 10 );
        button_set_text ( btn_new_game, L"Новая игра" );
        button_set_pos ( btn_new_game, 10, 400 );
        button_set_color ( btn_new_game, 0x2c2c2cff, 0x00002cff, 0xffe301 );
}

void render_menu ( )
{
        button_render ( btn_new_game );
}
button_set_color выглядит так.
void button_set_color ( struct button *btn, unsigned int color, unsigned int bcolor, unsigned int tcolor )
{
        btn->tcolor = tcolor;
        box_set_color ( btn->box, color, bcolor );
        font_free_texture ( btn->font );
        font_set_text ( btn->font, btn->text, btn->font_size, 1, 1, 4, btn->tcolor );
}
```

Функия используюет box_set_color, btn->box отвечает за прямоугольную или квадратную область в зависимости от размера. Вот код задания цвета box.

```
void box_set_color ( struct box *box, unsigned int color, unsigned int bcolor )
{
        box->color = color;
        box->bcolor = bcolor;
        for ( int y = 0, i = 0; y < box->height; y++ ) {
                for ( int x = 0; x < box->width; x++, i += 4 ) {
                        if ( x == 0 || x == box->width - 1 || y == 0 || y == box->height - 1 ) {
                                box->color_box[i + 0] = ( box->bcolor >> 24 & 0xff ) / 255.0f;
                                box->color_box[i + 1] = ( box->bcolor >> 16 & 0xff ) / 255.0f;
                                box->color_box[i + 2] = ( box->bcolor >>  8 & 0xff ) / 255.0f;
                                box->color_box[i + 3] = ( box->bcolor >>  0 & 0xff ) / 255.0f;
                                continue;
                        }
                        box->color_box[i + 0] = ( box->color >> 24 & 0xff ) / 255.0f;
                        box->color_box[i + 1] = ( box->color >> 16 & 0xff ) / 255.0f;
                        box->color_box[i + 2] = ( box->color >>  8 & 0xff ) / 255.0f;
                        box->color_box[i + 3] = ( box->color >>  0 & 0xff ) / 255.0f;
                }
        }
}
```

Я проверял, все нормально с цветом, он записывается в массив. В самом box инициализаторе вот какой код.

```
void box_init ( struct box *box )
{
        glm_clear_matrix4x4 ( &box->ortho[0] );
        glm_clear_matrix4x4 ( &box->translate[0] );

        box->program = global.programs[POINTS];
        int width = global.width;
        int height = global.height;
        glm_ortho ( &box->ortho[0], 0.0f, width, 0.0f, height, 0.0f, 1.0f );

        box->vertex_box = NULL;
        box->color_box = NULL;
        box->color = 0x000000ff;
        box->bcolor = 0xffffffff;
        box->x = 0;
        box->y = 0;

        glUseProgram ( box->program );
        box->translate_location = glGetUniformLocation ( box->program, "transform" );
        box->ortho_location = glGetUniformLocation ( box->program, "ortho" );
}
```

То есть всё нормально. Вот рендер box.

```
void box_render ( struct box *box )
{
        glUseProgram ( box->program );
        glUniformMatrix4fv ( box->translate_location, 1, GL_FALSE, &box->translate[0][0] );
        glUniformMatrix4fv ( box->ortho_location, 1, GL_FALSE, &box->ortho[0][0] );

        glEnableVertexAttribArray ( 0 );
        glEnableVertexAttribArray ( 1 );

        glVertexAttribPointer ( 0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, box->vertex_box );
        glVertexAttribPointer ( 1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, box->color_box );

        glDrawArrays ( GL_POINTS, 0, box->max_render );

        glDisableVertexAttribArray ( 0 );
        glDisableVertexAttribArray ( 1 );
}
```

С рендером тоже всё нормально. И вот шейдеры.

```
{
        const char *vshader =
                "#version 300 es\n"
                "layout(location = 0) in vec2 position;\n"
                "layout(location = 1) in vec4 color;\n"
                "uniform mat4 transform;\n"
                "uniform mat4 ortho;\n"
                "out vec4 v_color;\n"
                "void main ( )\n"
                "{\n"
                " gl_Position = ortho * transform * vec4 ( position, 0.0, 1.0 );\n"
                " v_color = color;\n"
                "}";
        const char *fshader =
                "#version 300 es\n"
                "precision mediump float;\n"
                "in vec4 v_color;\n"
                "out vec4 frag_color;\n"
                "void main ( )\n"
                "{\n"
                " frag_color = v_color;\n"
                "}";
        GLuint program = loadProgram ( vshader, fshader );
        global.programs[POINTS] = program;
}
```

В них вроде тоже всё нормально, но цвет box'а не выводит какой надо. И в чём же может быть проблема и разумеется как её решить?

Comment: Можете сделать [mcve]? Пока в голову приходит только попробовать подебажить вот этим: https://renderdoc.org/

Comment: @HolyBlackCat если только на github выложить, потому что кода много.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat всё, выложил **https://github.com/xverizex/pixelit**

Comment: Действительно, там много всего. Если получится так, что никто не захочет копаться в той куче кода, можно поступить как советуют по ссылке выше и сделать именно минимальный рабочий пример, убрав все лишнее.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat дело в том, что все файлы участвуют в том, чтобы вывести кнопку. Мне бы точно знать, может ли шейдер перемножать glortho * transform без ошибок, а то мне кажется что что-то в шейдерах. Хотя если были бы ошибки, были бы сообщения об этом. Блин. Другая программа работает нормально, но там матрицы не перемножаются как здесь.

Comment: Раз только цвет неправильный, а позиция правильная, значит и матрицы перемножаются правильно. Так?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да, но цвет я проверял в массиве, когда цвет задавал. Значит цвет передается правильный.

Comment: Говорю же, попробуйте renderdoc. В нем сможете посмотреть, правильный цвет приходит в шейдер или нет.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat хорошо, спасибо.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat блин у меня ubuntu, а не kubuntu, kde neon. В kde было бы нормально, но в ubuntu размер окна занимает два телевизора и кнопки большие и текст большой.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, перевел вывод box в текстуры, теперь работает нормально. А рисовать точками так и не получилось. Да может это и к лучшему, может треугольниками производительней рисовать, чем пикселями! Как вы думаете?

Comment: Только сейчас увидел, что вы рисовали точками. Конечно треугольники лучше! Рисовать кучу точек намного медленнее.